# Reading XML file by name

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file in the following format.

`<ComponentStream component="Path" name="path" componentId="DV005120211_40"><Samples><PathFeedrate dataItemId="DV005120211_47" timestamp="2013-05-14T02:26:12.0576" name="path_feedrate1" sequence="8608400">1440.0000000000</PathFeedrate><PathFeedrate dataItemId="DV005120211_48" timestamp="2013-05-09T19:30:45.0389Z" name="path_feedrate2" sequence="216">UNAVAILABLE</PathFeedrate><PathFeedrate dataItemId="DV005120211_49" timestamp="2013-05-09T19:30:45.0389Z" name="path_feedrate3" sequence="217">UNAVAILABLE</PathFeedrate><PathFeedrate dataItemId="DV005120211_50" timestamp="2013-05-09T19:30:45.0389Z" name="path_feedrate4" sequence="219">UNAVAILABLE</PathFeedrate><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_62" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro910" sequence="8099806">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_63" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro909" sequence="8099805">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_64" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro908" sequence="8099804">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_65" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro907" sequence="8099803">7.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_66" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro906" sequence="8099802">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_67" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro905" sequence="8099801">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_68" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro904" sequence="8099800">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_69" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro903" sequence="8099799">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_70" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro902" sequence="8099798">0.0000000000</PartCount><PartCount dataItemId="DV005120211_71" timestamp="2013-05-13T22:11:00.0639" name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro901" sequence="8099797">0.0000000000</PartCount>`

This is just a section. but if you notice the name="MacroSample_Head1_Macro907". I am trying to read the value of that. Which is 7.0.
I have tried using linq

```
string value7 = (string)(XElement.Load("http://B-DVM-4/current")
     .Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName == "MacroSample_Head1_Macro907"));
```

But I have got something wrong?

Comment: `But I have got something wrong?` - what did you get?

Comment: try FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName == "MacroSample_Head1_Macro907").Value

You're getting the element, but you need the contents of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently trying to find an *element* name of `MacroSample_Head1_Macro907` - whereas I believe you really want find an element named `PartCount` with an *attribute* called `name` with a value of `MacroSample_Head1_Macro907`:

```
var element = XElement.Load("http://B-DVM-4/current");
XNamespace ns = "urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectStreams:1.2";
var part = element.Descendants(ns + "PartCount")
                  .First(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == 
                              "MacroSample_Head1_Macro907")
                  .Value;
```

(Or you might want to cast to `decimal` instead of using `Value` - presumably it *is* a decimal value.)

Note that the namespace is declared as the default namespace by the root element:

```
<MTConnectStreams ... xmlns="urn:mtconnect.org:MTConnectStreams:1.2" ...>
    ...
</MTConnectStreams>
```

Comment: Well Pardon my ignorance, but how do I read this as a string? I am trying to get this value to show up in a message box.

Comment: @user2139891: Read what as a string? The `part` variable is already a `string` variable, just like `value7` in your original code.

Comment: Get an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception

Comment: @user2139891: Then you presumably don't have a `PartCount` element - perhaps it's actually in a different namespace? As you've only given us a tiny part of the XML, we can't really tell.

Comment: @user2139891: (I've changed FirstOrDefault to First though, to make it clear that you really do expect there to be a value.)

Comment: I have updated to show a little more of the XML I am working with.

Comment: Or better yet there is a similar XML you can get to via the web. At http://agent.mtconnect.org/current.

Comment: @user2139891: As I suspected, the element is in a namespace which you didn't mention. See my edited answer. Although the document you linked to doesn't include any PartCount elements.